# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.legacy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, siamese-network

Unable to find legacy module, I hope I can ask for help,[Siamese Network](https://github.com/tensorfreitas/Siamese-Networks-for-One-Shot-Learning) The code is the Siamese Network for One Shot Learining on Github, but I'm having problems running it.

```
    from tensorflow.keras.legacy import interfaces
    import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Optimizer
    import legacy
    from interface import interface



class Modified_SGD(Optimizer):
  @interface.legacy_get_updates_support
   def get_updates(self, loss, params):
      grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
      self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

      lr = self.lr
      if self.initial_decay > 0:
         lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                              K.dtype(self.decay))
```

Comment: Have you tried just `from keras.legacy import interfaces`?

Comment: Try this : import tensorflow.keras as keras